# I send packets through ppp link by scapy, why sr can't receive the reply? tcpdump ppp0 is ok

Tags: python, scapy, pppoe

I try to send icmp packets through ppp link, but sr can't receive the reply,  and tcpdump ppp0 is ok!

```
sh-4.2# tcpdump -i ppp0 -n icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode  
listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
23:52:58.595117 IP 219.240.73.152 > 106.120.159.142: ICMP echo request, id 10915, seq 1, length 8
23:52:58.618401 IP 106.120.159.142 > 219.240.73.152: ICMP echo reply, id 10915, seq 1, length 8
```

My code is as follows， and result is timeout！Scapy Version is 2.4.3

---

```
import os  
from scapy.all import *

conf.route.resync()  
packet = IP(dst="www.baidu.com")/ICMP(id=10915, seq=1)  
ans,unans = sr(packet, filter='icmp', verbose=0, timeout=3)  
if ans is None or len(ans) <= 0:  
    result = {"ans": len(ans), "unans": len(unans), "error": "timeout"}    
    print(result)  
    return

tx = ans[0][0]  
rx = ans[0][1]  
time = '%.2f' % ((rx.time-tx.sent_time) * 1000)   
ip = rx.sprintf("%IP.src%")   
result = {"ip": ip, "time": time}  
print(result)
```

Comment: Did you try passing the iface using `iface=` to sr?

Comment: i try to add, it still not works!  
ans,unans = sr(packet, filter='icmp', verbose=0, timeout=timeout, iface="ppp0")

Comment: it works! I add nofilter=True and iface="ppp0", thank you very much!